# Search-For Utility Mainframe Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mainframe, zos

Can someone please give me some pointers on how the IBM mainframe Search-For Utility algorithm works?

How does it compare strings? What kind of matching algorithm does it use? How should I enter different strings in order to make the less comparisons possible?

I am using the utility but I do not know how it works, and I believe I am not using it as well as I should.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Don't forget that z/OS UNIX Services includes a full and standards-compliant version of tools like "grep" that can do very sophisticated pattern matching with regular expressions on just about any mainframe data. If you come from another platform where regex is common, no need to give it up on z/OS. You can even use these tools with "//'dsn(member)'" syntax and for the most part, they work against conventional z/OS datasets as well as UNIX files.

Comment: Hello. First of all, thank you for your input.
I find this to be quite amiable. I had only used them with some commands and applying very basic regular expressions. After some brief search, I am still unsure on how to properly use them in order to take the maximum advantage of the mainframe capabilities. I guess I need a bit more hands on TSO. Thank you!

Comment: The trick is getting to know the UNIX Services shell on z/OS. There are various ways to do it...at one extreme, you can just use Telnet or SSH to connect directly to your mainframe and you'll see a UNIX shell that's nearly identical to what you'd see on Linux/UNIX. There are also things like the TSO "OMVS" command that gives you a shell that runs right inside your TSO session. These are great tools for anyone with UNIX skills coming to a mainframe since most everything will be immediately familiar to them.

Comment: Thanks Valerie. Will look into that. The greatest difficulty I'm facing right now, is after getting to know the first introduction to Z/OS and mainframe, how to get in deeper and understanding more and more about the mainframe environment and becoming familiar with its intricacies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it as a very dumb search.

It doesn't have the capacity to enter a REGEX or anything like that. I don't think anyone will be able to tell you what algorithm is used.

Search-For uses the SuperC program to actually perform the search. What it appears to do is search line by line for a match to the string you provided. So if I do a search for:

```
'PIC 9(9)'
```

I am going to get back results for every line that has that string in it. The only way I could bring back less search results, would be to add more to that string. So maybe search for:

`'PIC 9(9).'` `'PIC 9(9) VALUE` `'PIC 9(9) COMP'`

any of these 3 would provide less results than the first search. So if that string breaks a line like:

```
05 WS-SOME-VARIABLE PIC 9(9)
   VALUE 123456.
```

a search for `'PIC 9(9) VALUE'` will not return anything, but a search for `'PIC 9(9)'` would.

The more specific you are, the less search results you will get back. Depending on what you are looking for, you may be able to get better results by using Search-For in batch, or using File-Aid instead. Every specific scenario is different. So without knowing exactly what you are searching for and what your requirement it, its hard to tell you how to proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is quite enlightening.

I was mainly wondering since the time it is taking me to search a large PDS (about 15000 elements in the dataset) is considerable. Even though I am searching for around 50 characters per string, I was thinking that a better way might exist. And I was also interested in getting to know what was the complexity of the algorithm implemented by IBM (time complexity and number of comparisons per pattern or text).

Another thing. What are the gains of using search-for in batch versus the search-for tool? What is the difference?

Comment: Doing your search in batch means that your terminal is not tied up whilst the search is done. What do you consider 'considerable time'? 15,000 in about 5 minutes is not a long time. Consider all the allocation/deallocation of each member which is what takes the most time per each member search.

Comment: Thank for your help. Sorry for the beginner question.
I was not focusing at all on the allocation/deallocation of each member. That might be quite bothersome.
Thank you for shedding some light on the problem. I was only seeing a supermachine doing a comparison in 5 minutes. Still, if it were not for the allocation/deallocation phase I would not be very happy with the mainframe performance. That or I was doing something seriously wrong!
Thank for your time.

Comment: You might try adding BUFNO= to the NEWDD statement, if most of the PDS member sizes would span several blocks, for a number > 5 (the default). However, this will not work if ISRSUPC (ASMASUPC) is using BPAM to read the members, as BUFNO is a QSAM-only parameter. (I do suspect it is using BPAM, as it would be easier to read members using this access method (and BPAM is already reading a block at a time)).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider IBM Developer for z, which which can do regular expression based searches. When the Remote Systems Explorer Daemon (RSED) is setup and running on the z/OS lpar, you can do searches across a single PDS or groups of PDS's using IDz filters. Very powerful. It also searches in the background so you can do other tasks while it searches. The searches can be saved for future ease of reference.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I did not know about this suite. It seems very interesting. Unfortunetely using it, is not an option for my company. Nonetheless I will be looking into it, since it seems to have great advantages to perform seemingly difficult tasks.